# For Loops inside For Loops inside For Loops... = Problems

Tags: javascript, cryptography, vigenere

So. I have 4 for loops inside other for loops in JS, and my code appears (FireBug agrees with me) that my code is syntactically sound, and yet it refuses to work. I'm attempting to calculate the key length in a vigenere cipher through the use of the Index of Coincidence, and Kappa tests <- if that helps any.

My main problem is that the task seems to be too computationally intensive for Javascript to run, as Firefox shoots up past 1GB of memory usage, and 99% CPU when I attempt to run the keylengthfinder() function. Any ideas of how to solve this problem, even if it takes much longer to calculate, would be greatly appreciated. Here's a link to the same code - http://pastebin.com/uYPBuZZz - Sorry about any indenting issues in this code. I'm having issues putting it on the page correctly.

```
function indexofcoincidence(text){
    text = text.split(" ").join("").toUpperCase();
    var textL = text.length;
    var hashtable = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (d=0; d<=25; d++) {
        for (i=0; i < textL; i++){
            if (text.charAt(i) === alphabet.charAt(d)){
            hashtable[d] = hashtable[d] + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    var aa = hashtable[0]/textL;
    var A = aa*aa;
    var bb = hashtable[1]/textL;
    var B = bb*bb;
    var cc = hashtable[2]/textL;
    var C = cc*cc;
    var dd = hashtable[3]/textL;
    var D = dd*dd;
    var ee = hashtable[4]/textL;
    var E = ee*ee;
    var ff = hashtable[5]/textL;
    var F = ff*ff;
    var gg = hashtable[6]/textL;
    var G = gg*gg;
    var hh = hashtable[7]/textL;
    var H = hh*hh;
    var ii = hashtable[8]/textL;
    var I = ii*ii;
    var jj = hashtable[9]/textL;
    var J = jj*jj;
    var kk = hashtable[10]/textL;
    var K = kk*kk;
    var ll = hashtable[11]/textL;
    var L = ll*ll;
    var mm = hashtable[12]/textL;
    var M = mm*mm;
    var nn = hashtable[13]/textL;
    var N = nn*nn;
    var oo = hashtable[14]/textL;
    var O = oo*oo;
    var pp = hashtable[15]/textL;
    var P = pp*pp;
    var qq = hashtable[16]/textL;
    var Q = qq*qq;
    var rr = hashtable[17]/textL;
    var R = rr*rr;
    var ss = hashtable[18]/textL;
    var S = ss*ss;
    var tt = hashtable[19]/textL;
    var T = tt*tt;
    var uu = hashtable[20]/textL;
    var U = uu*uu;
    var vv = hashtable[21]/textL;
    var V = vv*vv;
    var ww = hashtable[22]/textL;
    var W = ww*ww;
    var xx = hashtable[23]/textL;
    var X = xx*xx;
    var yy = hashtable[24]/textL;
    var Y = yy*yy;
    var zz = hashtable[25]/textL;
    var Z = zz*zz;

    var Kappa = A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z;
    var Top = 0.027*textL;
    var Bottom1 = 0.038*textL + 0.065;
    var Bottom2 = (textL - 1)*Kappa;
    var KeyLength = Top/(Bottom2 - Bottom1) ;

    return Kappa/0.0385;
}

function keylengthfinder(text){
    // Average Function Definition
    Array.prototype.avg = function() {
        var av = 0;
        var cnt = 0;
        var len = this.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var e = +this[i];
            if(!e && this[i] !== 0 && this[i] !== '0') e--;
            if (this[i] == e) {av += e; cnt++;}
    }
        return av/cnt;
    }
    // Begin the Key Length Finding
    var textL = text.length;
    var hashtable = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        for (a = 0; a <= 12; a++){ // This is the main loop, testing each key length
            var stringtable = [];
            for (z = 0; z <= a; z++){ // This allows each setting, ie. 1st, 4th, 7th AND 2nd, 5th, 8th to be tested
                for (i = z; i < textL; i + a){
                    var string = '';
                    string = string.concat(text.charAt(i)); // Join each letter of the correct place in the string
                    stringtable[z] = indexofcoincidence(string);
                    }
                }
            hashtable[a] = stringtable.avg();
        }
    return hashtable;
}
```

Comment: Very hard to follow the code without proper indentation.

Comment: What's the length of `text`? Seems like the complexity should be more or less `O(text.length^2)`. Also, please indent your code more readably.

Comment: Sorry about the code indents. I'm working on fixing it now. Sorry about that. Text is designed to be any length.

Comment: Also, you might want to remove variables you use to cache values like `text.length`, they're unlikely to be what's killing the performance and harm readability more than help it.

Comment: So it would be more efficient to call text.length every time I need it, rather than define it in a variable?

Comment: The performance bound for this is like 12 * 12 * n * 25 * n, with 144 * n of those 25 * n function calls.  If the string has 100 characters, that's 36 million iterations (roughly). For 1000 characters, it's around 36 billion. Right? What's the length of the string you're testing with?

Comment: Oh wow. I'm normally using around 1500 character blocks of encrypted text to test this. How should I go about bringing this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.avg = function() {...}
```

should be only done once, and not every time `keylengthfinder` is called.

```
var Top = 0.027*textL;
var Bottom1 = 0.038*textL + 0.065;
var Bottom2 = (textL - 1)*Kappa;
var KeyLength = Top/(Bottom2 - Bottom1) ;
return Kappa/0.0385;
```

Why do you computer those variables if you don't use them at all?

```
var string = '';
string = string.concat(text.charAt(i)); // Join each letter of the correct place in the string
stringtable[z] = indexofcoincidence(string);
```

I don't know what you are trying to do in here. The `string` will always be only one character?

```
for (i = z; i < textL; i + a) {
    ...
    stringtable[z] = ...
}
```

In this loop, you are computing values for `i` from `z` to `textL` - but you overwrite the same array item each time. So it would be enough to compute the `stringtable[z]` for `i=textL-1` - or your algorithm is flawed.

A much shorter and more concise variant of the `indexofcoincidence` function:

```
function indexofcoincidence(text){
    var l = text.replace(/ /g, "").length;
    text = text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "");
    var hashtable = {};
    for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        var c = text.charAt(i);
        hashtable[c] = (hashtable[c] || 0) + 1;
    }
    var kappa = 0;
    for (var c in hashtable)
        kappa += hashtable[c] * hashtable[c];
    return kappa/(l*l)/0.0385;
}
```

---

All right. Now that we found your problem (including the infinite loop in case `a=0`, as detected by qw3n), let's rewrite the loop:

```
function keylengthfinder(text) {
    var length = text.length,
        probabilities = []; // probability by key length
        maxkeylen = 13; // it might make more sense to determine this in relation to length

    for (var a = 1; a <= maxkeylen; a++) { // testing each key length
        var stringtable = Array(a); // strings to check with this gap
        // read "a" as stringtable.length
        for (var z = 0; z < a; z++) {
            var string = '';
            for (var i = z; i < textL; i += a) {
                string += text.charAt(i);
            }
            // a string consisting of z, z+a, z+2a, z+3a, ... -th letters
            stringtable[z] = string;
        }
        var sum = 0;
        // summing up the coincidence indizes for current stringtable
        for (var i=0; i<a; i++) {
            sum += indexofcoincidence(stringtable[i]);
        }
        probabilities[a] = sum / a; // average
    }
    return probabilities;
}
```

Every of the loop statements has changed against your original script!

- Never forget to declare the running variable to be local (`var` keyword)
- `a` needs to start at zero - a key must have a minimum length of 1
- to run from 1 to n, use `i=1; i<=n; i++`
- to run from 0 to n-1, use `i=0; i<n; i++` (nearly all loops, especially on zero-based array indizes).
- Other loops than those two never occur in normal programs. You should get suspicious if you have loops from 0 to n or from 1 to n-1...
- The update expression needs to update the running variable. `i++` is a shortcut for `i+=1` is a shortcut for `i=i+1`. Your expression, `i + a`, did *not* assign the new value (apart from the `a=0` problem)!

Comment: 1. Thanks for that. I didn't realize it was in the loop
            2. Because I was, and still am, wary of doing a large calculation in one line/any tip on this would be appreciated.
            3. With the string variable, I was trying to continually append say. the 2nd, 5th, 8th... letters into the string before finding the indexofcoincidence. How should I fix this?

Comment: 1. Not in a loop, in the outermost function 2. My point is not on doing large calculations, but on not using their results - you could leave out the whole calculation. 3. If you want to continually append, you are not allowed to init the string each round :-) However, I still don't understand what you really want to do. Could you give me a example for the iterations with a short string, say "abcdef"?

Comment: Okay. So I'm implementing the methods described here - http://s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/123882/1/ - And I've gotten as far as this quote "We average these three ICs and call it the result for key length three."

So. What should happen is that I'm trying to find the indexofcoincidence function for each set of possible key lengths - 1 through 12. And in order to do that, for an example key length of two, I need to isolate the 1,3,5,7,9 characters, and the 2,4,6,8 characters, then find the indexofcoincidence, and then average the two. If that makes any sense.

Comment: OK. I've written some nested loops that do what you need (creating the strings for each key length and start index, averaging coincidence of all strings with same length and store that by length).

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that I have a long way to go before I'm competent with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is definitely right here

```
for (i = z; i < textL; i + a){
  var string = '';
  string = string.concat(text.charAt(i)); // Join each letter of the correct place in the string
  stringtable[z] = indexofcoincidence(string);
 }
```

Notice that if `a=0` i never changes and therefore you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: Awesome. This seems to have fixed a lot of it, thanks so much!

Now, the section inside of that loop is giving me problems. I'm trying to isolate every 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th letter, etc, and then run the Indexofcoincidence() function on it. The "string" variable seems to be limited to once character. Suggestions? And thanks again!